# Select All/UnSelect All checkboxes anything under parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing select all/unselect all checkbox. I am missing something select checkbox in jquery code.

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").click(function() {
  //alert(this.checked);
  if (this.checked) { // check select status
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('.checkbox1').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input  id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="false">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input  id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="false">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: why are you doing the `$('.checkbox1').each(function() {` part? seems unnecessary

Comment: Didn't you forget to set the checkboxes class to `checkbox1`? or is there some other method you planned to "select" them?

Comment: What should happen if someone change the child checkboxes? Should the "all" box respond accordingly?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/66agjdza/

Comment: @j08691 thats true. if user select all checkboxes selectall checkbox should select

Answer (score 2):

You enclose the `target` with one `div`, so you should use `.parents` to find there common `parent` which should be `.outer-part`.

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_']").click(function() {
  alert(this.checked);
  $(this).parents(".outer-part").find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$("input[type='checkbox']:not([id^='chk_']").click(function() {
  // Get parents
  var $parent = $(this).parents(".outer-part");
  // Create selctor for check condition
  var checkedSelector = this.checked ? ":checked" : ":not(:checked)";
  // Create selector to get all checkbox exclude select all.
  var exluceSelector = 'input[type="checkbox"]:not([id^="chk_"])';
  // Get items
  var boxes  = $parent.find(exluceSelector);
  // Check if length after filter is the same.
  if (boxes.length === boxes.filter(checkedSelector).length) {
    console.log(this.checked);
    $("input[id^='chk_']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: how to do wise versa. if user select all checkboxes , selectall checkbox also should select

Comment: Updated with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code:

1. The `$('.checkbox1').each(function() {` is not necessary as there aren't any checkboxes with class checkbox1.
2. Doing `$(this).parent()` is not enough because you will only go to the div that is containing the "check all" checkbox, you need to do `.parent().parent()`

Once that's fixed, it seems to work fine:

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").click(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
    if (this.checked) { // check select status
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        //$('.checkbox1').each(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
       // });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

In order to uncheck/uncheck the Select all checkbox when all/not all the checkboxes are selected, you need to add a listener to each checkbox

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").click(function() {
    console.log(this.checked);
    if (this.checked) { // check select status
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        //$('.checkbox1').each(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
       // });
    }
    });

$(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if ($(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']:checked").length < $(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']").length) {
        console.log("not all checked");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_']").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        console.log("all checked");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_']").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

This could be simplified by using `.parents()` and removing the `if` clause and assigning the value directly to the checkboxes as suggested by [fuyushimoya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277572/3695983) (you could probably simplify the selector too, right now it looks ugly).

The resulting code making both changes would look like this:

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".outer-part").find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".outer-part").find("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_']").prop("checked", $(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == $(".outer-part div:not(div[id^='divSelectAll']) input[type='checkbox']").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: how to do wise versa. if user select all checkboxes , selectall checkbox also should select

Comment: Added it, although the selector looks really ugly and could be improved

Comment: you code works great. but it is always going `console.log("not all checked");` even after I selected all checkboxes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior

Answer (score 0):

Poor html formatting resulted in human errors.

The following works fine.

```
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) { // check select status
        $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
        <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>

    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
            <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
            <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bs42uy3/2/)

Comment: how to do wise versa. if user select all checkboxes , selectall checkbox also should select

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").click(function() {
  if (this.checked) { // check select status
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){$(this).prop('checked', true);});
  } else {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){$(this).prop('checked', false);});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
    <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All <a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap">View All Descriptions</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false">Completion Planning
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row padding-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input checked="checked" id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true">
      <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false">Drilling
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work with all the checkboxes (parent and child):

```js
$('#chk_DRILLING').click(function () {
    $('.row.padding-4 > .col-md-12 > input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
})
$('.row.padding-4 > .col-md-12 > input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var checked = $('.row.padding-4 > .col-md-12 > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    var total = $('.row.padding-4 > .col-md-12 > input[type="checkbox"]').length;
    if (checked === total) $('#chk_DRILLING').prop({
        'checked': true,
            'indeterminate': false
    });
    if (!checked) $('#chk_DRILLING').prop({
        'checked': false,
            'indeterminate': false
    });
    if (checked > 0 && checked < total) $('#chk_DRILLING').prop('indeterminate', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row outer-part col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12 TechDiscSelectAll" id="divSelectAll_DRILLING">
        <input id="chk_DRILLING" name="chk_DRILLING" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="chk_DRILLING" type="hidden" value="false">&nbsp; Select All / Unselect All<a id="lnkViewAll_DRILLING" class="NoWrap" />View All Descriptions</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="CPDI" name="CPDI" type="checkbox" value="true" />
            <input name="CPDI" type="hidden" value="false" />Completion Planning</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input  id="DDA" name="DDA" type="checkbox" value="true" />
            <input name="DDA" type="hidden" value="false" />Drilling</div>
    </div>
</div>
```